# How to recover data around corrupted data in table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, corruption

I have a SQL Server database with some corrupted data unrepairable via DBCC CHECKDB in a table. I can get many of the rows before the corruption out - but how do I get the rows after the corruption out?

Comment: What exactly is corrupted on your table?  Is it the clustered index (or heap) or a nonclustered index?  Are you able to put the `DBCC CHECKDB` output in your question?

Comment: Paul Randal recently updated his corruption demos, you might check those scripts. Good way to test before doing in production too: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/corruption-demo-databases-and-scripts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I truncated the table as the data wasn't essential and this cleared out the corruption. I know this won't be a solution for most folks - usually you need the data.